# How can I update the text values in the UITextfield in a reusable tableView cell, with different values in each cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am making a currency converter that updates currencies simultaneously as you type. The currencies are held in a tableView and the cell is a custom cell.

I want to be able to type into one cell, and see all the other cells update with the value from the conversion calculation. The calculation works, but I am not sure how to get the data back into the correct cells, as essentially there is only one as it is a reusable cell.

Here is the cell class, (I am just showing the input to keep things clear.):

```
class PageCell: UITableViewCell {

let cellCalcInput = UITextField()

func configureCustomCell() {

    contentView.addSubview(cellCalcInput)
    cellCalcInput.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellCalcInput.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    cellCalcInput.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    cellCalcInput.font = secondFont?.withSize(18)
    cellCalcInput.textColor = .white
    cellCalcInput.placeholder = "Enter an amount"
    cellCalcInput.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    cellCalcInput.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    cellCalcInput.backgroundColor = .clear

    cellCalcInput.isHidden = true
    self.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    contentView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Next I create the cells, I am showing more so that you get the idea of how I am setting the data for each cell to the selected currency.

Then I add a textFieldDidChange listener:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var coinName = String()
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    let cell:PageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PageCell") as! PageCell
    cell.configureCustomCell()
    let index = indexPath.row
    let coins = Manager.shared.coins
    let coin = coins[index]
    var coinIndex = Int()
    coinIndex = CGPrices.shared.coinData.index(where: { $0.id == coin })!
    let unit = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates[defaultCurrency]!.unit
    coinIndexes.append(coinIndex)

    //Prices from btc Exchange rate.
    let btcPrice = CGPrices.shared.coinData[coinIndex].current_price!
    let dcExchangeRate = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates[defaultCurrency]!.value
    let realPrice = (btcPrice*dcExchangeRate)

    setBackground(dataIndex: coinIndex, contentView: cell.contentView)

    coinName = CGPrices.shared.coinData[coinIndex].name

    let imageString = CGPrices.shared.coinData[coinIndex].image 
    cell.theImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "CryptiXJustX"))

    cell.cellTextLabel.text = coinName
    cell.cellDetailLabel.text = "\(unit)\((round(1000*realPrice)/1000))"

    cell.cellCalcInput.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

// here is the text listener

```
    return cell
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    var index = Int()
    index = textField.tag

    if textField.text != "" {
    calculations(dataIndex: index, calcInput: textField)
    } else {
        print("no text")
    }

}
```

and here is where I do the calculation when it is typed, and get the results, it is not complete but I need to now somehow get these results shown inside the UITextfield for each cell, relating to the correct currency.

```
    var coinIndexes = [Int]()
var answers = [Double]()
//
var comparitorIndex = 0
func calculations(dataIndex: Int, calcInput: UITextField) {
    let exchangeRate = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates[defaultCurrency]!.value
//
    let btcPrice = CGPrices.shared.coinData[dataIndex].current_price!

//
    if answers.count < coinIndexes.count {

        var calculation = ""
        if CGPrices.shared.coinData[dataIndex].id == "bitcoin" {
            calculation = String(Double(calcInput.text!)! / btcPrice)
        } else {
        calculation = String(Double(calcInput.text!)! * btcPrice)
        }
        let calcAsDouble = Double(calculation)
        let calcFinal = Double(round(1000*calcAsDouble!)/1000)

        var comparitor = coinIndexes[comparitorIndex]
        var comparitorPrice = CGPrices.shared.coinData[comparitor].current_price!

        var comparitorAnswer = (calcFinal/comparitorPrice)
        answers.append(comparitorAnswer)

        comparitorIndex += 1
        print(comparitorAnswer)
        calculations(dataIndex: dataIndex, calcInput: calcInput)
    }
    comparitorIndex = 0

}
```

Here basically I do the calculations based on which cell is being typed and I can find out which currency it is from the tag, and then using the index of the currency I can check my API and get its name and values, then I do the calculation to compare the other currencies to the value that the user entered. The calculations work and give the correct results, I just don't know how to send the results back into the correct cells. Thank you.

Sorry if it is very sloppy work I am still very new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your results in a dictionary type `[Int : Double]` where `Int` is the `coinIndex`, and `Double` part is the answer from the conversion. Then, after your calculations finish, you can call `tableView.reloadData.()`.

You also need to make modifications to your `cellForRowAt` to show the conversion.

Try this:

In your UIViewController, declare

```
var conversions: [Int : Double] = [:]
```

Then in `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // your code here
    let conversion = conversions[index]
    // the ?? operator will pass "No Value" string if conversion is nil.
    cell.cellCalcInput.text = String(conversion ?? "No Value")
}
```

You need to update the conversions in your calculation function

```
func calculations(dataIndex: Int, calcInput: UITextField) {
    // your code here
    conversions[comparatorIndex] = comparatorAnswer
    // once all conversions are entered
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I think you can improve your `calculations` function. You can iterate on the coin index instead of updating the answers recursively. Good luck!

Comment: This is looking great! thank you! For the part in cellForRowAt, I can't do that until I've entered something into a text box or it finds nil, but that may also be because I've changed it to `let conversion = conversions[index]
        cell.cellCalcInput.text = String(Double(conversion!))` and force unwrapped as with your original code I got an error: 'Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Double?)'' Any Ideas?

Comment: I can probably just use a Boolean that sets true from textDidChange to check if that is True before doing `cell.cellCalcInput.text = String(conversion)` So it is only called if there is definitely a value in the textInput. Will check this when I can and accept when I have it all working!

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use the `??` operator to check if a value is nil, and if it is, pass an alternative value. For the case of String(Double(conversion!)), keep in mind that the `Double(String)` constructor will return an optional, because not all strings are convertible to double.

Comment: Thank you, got that working. When you say I can improve my calculations function can you possibly elaborate on that? The final problem I am having is handling all the indexes and the calculation before adding them to `conversions` dictionary. I am trying to get a dictionary of the indexes and the original price, and then perform the calculation on each item in that dict, and putting that answer back into the conversions dictionary, but I am unsure how to format this. Thank you.

Comment: That would indeed be a neater solution. Keep in mind you can iterate through each key-value pair in the dictionary using a `for` loop. So your `comparator` will be the key in the dictionary, and you will use `dataIndex` to calculate the rates. This way, you can put all calculation logic in the `for` loop and do away with the recursion!

Comment: Thank you I have done what you said and it is perfect. The only problem now is with the tableView cell. It is all setup, calculations working perfectly and a very neat conversions dictionary, but as I have done `cell.cellCalcInput.text = String(Double(conversion ?? 0)` and `tableView.reloadData()` after the calculation, because I need a default that can't be "No Text" as that is a string, and any other way I type it gives me an error, (also the calcInput is the same I type and the same that gives result) I can't actually type anything as it reloads to 0.0! I know it is possible to do.

Comment: But you have answered my main question so thanks alot! hopefully I will figure it out soon!